# Can not send props value in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I want to sent props value CategoryLink component to Store component. Could not sent props value **CategoryLink.jsx** to **Store.jsx**. I want to send this props `<Store test="test"/>`  to Store.jsx component. What I am missing could you please check my code.

Note: I am using props already Store.jsx component again want to use another props values how to use multiprops in store component.

**File Location: ComponentList/CategoryLink.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
// import {withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Store from '../StoreComponent/Store';
export default class CategoryLink extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: [],
      isLoading: true,
    };
    
  }
  render(){
    // var a=this.props.url_test;
    
    return (
      <div>
        <Store test="test"/>  
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**File Location: StoreComponent/Store.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
// import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";
import { Grid, Image, Icon } from "semantic-ui-react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import TopMenuStrip from "../ComponentList/TopMenuStrip";
import LogoSection from "../ComponentList/LogoSection"; 
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import OfferList from "./OfferList";
import Related from "./Related";
import CopyRight from "../ComponentList/CopyRight";
import CategoryLink from "../ComponentList/CategoryLink";
import Footer from "../ComponentList/Footer"; 
import CustomerReview from "./CustomerReview";
class Store extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: [],
      isLoading: true,
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
     
    console.log(this.props)
    let url_id = this.props.match.params.id; 
    const url = "http://localhost:3000/api/v5/web/details";
    const postBody = {
      store_id: url_id,
      offer_type: "",
    };
    const requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(postBody),
    };

    fetch(url, requestOptions)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        this.setState({ data: json });
        // console.log(json);
        // console.log(json);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => {
        this.setState({ isLoading: false });
      });
  }

  render() {
    var i; 
    // console.log(location)
    if (!this.state.data.how_to) {
      return null;
    }
    if (!this.state.data.store_terms) {
      return null;
    }
    const catId=this.state.data.category_id;
    // const catName=this.state.data.category_name;
    const seokeyWord = this.state.data.seo_keywords; 
    // console.log(membership_offers.length) 
    // console.log(this.state.data.rating)
    // console.log(seoDescription)
    return (
      <>
      <TopMenuStrip />
        <LogoSection /> 
        
        <div>
        <Grid className="breadcrumb-section">
            <Grid.Column width={16}>
            <div class="ui breadcrumb">
               <a href="http://localhost:3000" class="section">Home</a>
               <i class="right angle icon divider"></i>          
               <a href={"http://localhost:3000" + this.props.test} class="section">{this.state.data.category_name}</a>
               <i class="right angle icon divider"></i>
               <a href={"http://localhost:3000" + this.props.match.url}class="active section">{this.state.data.store_name}</a>
            </div>
              </Grid.Column>
         </Grid>     
          
          <Grid className="storedetails">
            <Grid.Column width={11}>
              <div className="storeImage">
                <div className="store-bg">
                  <h1>
                    {this.state.data.store_name}
                    
                  </h1>
                  
                  <h2>
                  <span className="store-right">
                      {
                        (i =
                          0 < this.state.data.rating ? (
                            <p>
                              <span className="rateNumber">
                                {this.state.data.rating}
                              </span>
                              <Icon id={i} className="star"></Icon>
                            </p>
                          ) : ( 
                            // <p className="no-reviews">No Reviews</p>
                            <></>
                          ))
                      }
                    </span>
                    </h2>
                  <p className="store-category"><span>{this.state.data.category_name}</span> </p>
                  <p className="">{this.state.data.summary} </p>
                  {/* <p><span className='rateNumber'>{this.state.data.rating}</span><Icon className='star'/><Icon className='star'/><Icon className='star'/><Icon className='star'/><Icon className='star'/><span className='totalRate'>39000</span></p> */}
                  {/* <div
                    className="store-back"
                    Style={
                      "background: url(" + this.state.data.store_images + ")"
                    }
                  > */}
                  <div> 
                    {/* <Image src= alt="" className='storeImage'/> */}
                    <Image
                      src={this.state.data.store_images}
                      alt={this.state.data.store_name +" - UAE"}
                      className="store-back"
                      Style="width: 100%;"
                    />
                    <Image
                      src={this.state.data.logo}
                      alt=""
                      className="storeImageLogo"
                    />
                     <Image
                      src="/images/logo512.png"
                      alt=""
                      className="store-logo"
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="related-section">
                  <OfferList />
                  </div>
              </div>
            </Grid.Column>
            <Grid.Column className="four-1" width={5}>
              <div className="storeAbout" centered>
                <h3>About</h3>
                <p
                  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                    __html: this.state.data.description,
                  }}
                ></p>
              </div>
              <CustomerReview />
              <Related categoryId={catId}/>
            </Grid.Column>
            
          </Grid>
          <Grid className="related-footer">
            <Grid.Column width={16}> 
            
            </Grid.Column>
          </Grid>
        </div>
        <Footer />
        <CopyRight />
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Store);
```

Comment: Are you just trying to access the `this.props.test` value? What isn't working?

Comment: I am using this.props.test inside of store component but can't get data. Store.jsx and CategoryLink component deferent location.

Comment: What do you mean? `CategoryLink` is rendering `Store` and passing it a `test` prop. Are you rendering more than one `Store` component, another one elsewhere?

Comment: Yes i need another one

Comment: Ok, please update your question to include the relevant code you've an issue with then.

Comment: I updated my question and added NOTE point above

Comment: Sorry, I don't see where you added the relevant code where a `this.props.test` would be undefined. I'm guessing you are rendering a `Store` component *somewhere* and ***not*** passing a `test` prop.

Answer (score -1):

While passing whichever component to a child in React, you should always enclose it in "{" and "}" as it is the syntax you must follow while passing any props in React.

```
...
 <Store test={"test"}/>  
...
```

Comment: I followed above code but i checked my Store.jsx 
 console.log("Result"+this.props.test)// undefined error shown

Comment: This is incorrect, strings can be passed directly, i.e. `test="test"` is valid syntax. https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#string-literals